# JDesktopPane ContainerListener and JInternalFrame iconified events

Tags: java, swing

So I have a desktoPane and it has containerListener. I have this containerListener to add or remove buttons from taskbar when you add or remove internal frames. Everything was ok while I haven't clicked to minimize icon (-). It came clear that when you minimize internalFrame it throws two events:

1. InternalFrame was removed;
2. DesktopIcon was added

and when you click restore it has again has two events:

1. DesktopIcon was removed;
2. InternalFrame was added

As a result when you click minimize the button from taskbar disappears. So the question - how can I distinguish between "normal" events when you yourself add internalframe to desktopPane and these iconified events?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use a `ContainerListener` for this. That's a fairly low-level interface for watching the component hierarchy. Instead use `JInternalFrame.addInternalFrameListener`. The [`InternalFrameListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/event/InternalFrameListener.html) interface fires dedicated methods for the opening, closing, minimizing and restoring events.

Comment: Thank you for your time. The problem is that internal frames are developed by another man and he uses this listener. So if I use it too I will override his listener as I don't know how to merge two listeners if it possible. That's why I use container listener...

Comment: You mean, he also uses an InternalFrameListener? That's not a problem. You can add as many listeners of the same type as you want. All the listeners will receive events.

Comment: Thank you again. Yes, he also uses internal frame listener. I thought that we can add only one listener of one type. Where can I read about what you say?

Comment: Nope, listeners don't replace one another. See the statement in the [event listener tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/intro.html): "Multiple listeners can register to be notified of events of a particular type from a particular source."  Also see, for example, the method [`JInternalFrame.getInternalFrameListeners()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JInternalFrame.html#getInternalFrameListeners--) : "Returns an array of all the InternalFrameListeners added to this JInternalFrame with addInternalFrameListener."